# Bibliography undefined errors

Tags: bibliographies

This is a working example that provides multiple error messages including that it couldn't find the authors. It doesn't accept any style format, including apastyle.

Error message:

```
    This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015)
The top-level auxiliary file: stackover.aux
I couldn't open style file apastyle.bst
---line 5 of file stackover.aux
 : \bibstyle{apastyle
 :                   }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I couldn't open database file bib.bib
---line 6 of file stackover.aux
 : \bibdata{bib
 :             }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no database files---while reading file stackover.aux
I found no style file---while reading file stackover.aux
(There were 4 error messages)
```

[image]

The tex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{verbatim}
 \usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{comment}

\def\bibfont{\small}%
\def\bibsep{\smallskipamount}%
\def\bibhang{24pt}%
\def\newblock{\ }%
\def\BIBand{and}%


\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}

\begin{document}


\section{Introduction}

\citep{Hart1995}

\citet{Li2015}
\citep{Chandrasekaran2008}



\bibliographystyle{apastyle}
\bibliography{bib} 


\end{document}
```

The bib file:

```
@ARTICLE{Li2015,
  AUTHOR =      {Li, Y. and Tellis, G.J.},
  TITLE =       { Does Province Matter? Intra-Country Differences in the Takeoff of New Products},
  JOURNAL =     {Technovation},
  YEAR =        {2015},
  volume =      { N/A},
  number =      { N/A},
  pages =       {N/A},
}

@ARTICLE{Hart1995,
  AUTHOR =      {Hart, S. L.},
  TITLE =       {A natural resource-based view of the firm},
  JOURNAL =     {Academy of Management Review},
  YEAR =        {1995},
  volume =      {20},
  number =      {4},
  pages =       {986-1014},
}

@ARTICLE{Chandrasekaran2008,
  AUTHOR =       {Chandrasekaran, D. and Tellis, G. J. },
  TITLE =        {Global takeoff of new products: Culture, wealth or vanishing differences? },
  JOURNAL =      {Marketing Science},
  YEAR =         {2008 },
  volume =       { 27},
  number =       { 5},
  pages =        { 844-860},
}
```

Comment: Please, don't post picture of your output, but include it as text. Your MWE also compiles fine, your error is not reproducible.

Comment: You have a `&` in one of your entries ("Thames & Hudson"). Try replacing it with `\&`, as `&` is special to LaTeX.

Comment: I just replaced it. Now, the roar message in bibtex is: I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no style file---while reading file

Comment: I replaced the last picture with text.

Comment: Why only the last? If the error occurs in the third step, you even don't need to include the fourth step. 
I still cannot reproduce your problem. Please add a [working MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). You could also update your question with your current error message - your last comment is not really meaningful.

Comment: I am not sure - the working example is not working either. I am attaching it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `apastyle` bibliography style. This is what the message

> I couldn't open style file apastyle.bst

tells you.
However, there is `apalike`, which works with your example.
So, replace

```
\bibliographystyle{apastyle}
```

with

```
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
```

You should also make sure that you reference the correct file with `\bibliography`. You say `\bibliography{bib}`, but bibtex says there is no such file:

> I couldn't open database file bib.bib

Comment: Yes, you are correct. apastyle was the problem. Thank you.